# Getting errors adding Buefy to Nuxt

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, bulma, buefy

I have a Nuxt project. I've installed Buefy via the [steps outlined in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-buefy). That is:

1. Run `npm i nuxt-buefy`
2. Add `'nuxt-buefy'` to `modules` in nuxt.config.js

I then run the dev server via

```
npm run dev
```

...and I get this gumf below. Thing is, Buefy doesn't say anything about having to first add `postcss-custom-properties`. What am I doing wrong?

```
 ERROR  Cannot find module 'postcss-custom-properties'                                                                                                                                     18:54:24  
Require stack:
- C:\Users\mitya\Sync\dev\projects\rpar\node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js

  Require stack:
  - node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
  at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:94:19)
  at m (node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:52953)
  at Resolver.f [as _require] (node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:53766)
  at Resolver.requireModule (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:381:29)
  at node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:603:58
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at PostcssConfig$1.loadPlugins (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:602:10)
  at PostcssConfig$1.config (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:638:14)
  at StyleLoader.postcss (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:909:39)
  at StyleLoader.apply (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:969:12)
  at WebpackClientConfig.rules (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:1357:28)
```

Comment: Did you tried this one? https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1670#issuecomment-330078867

Comment: Same deal. I don't have postcss installed (at least, I haven't installed it) - does this mean I need to add it? If so, wouldn't you expect the Buefy docs to make this clear? Arghhhhhhh NPM can be painful...

Comment: If it's a dependency, it may be required or not documented maybe yeah. As of why this is not documented, maybe because of different package versions. Also, I think that this package may not be used by a lot of people, hence why this issue is not documented.

Comment: I configured Buefy with the `buefy` package, since it allowed more flexibility. I may maybe make a public repo with the setup.

Comment: Thanks @kissu. Yeah I created a brand new Nuxt project just now and this time added Buefy when `create-nuxt-app` asks you if you want to add any CSS frameworks. *This* time, it works fine, even though, to my eyes, the nuxt.config.js and package.json files look just the same as when I tried to install Buefy manually, after the fact. Weird...

Comment: The configuration is maybe elsewhere actually.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, scaffolding a brand new Nuxt project was still the easiest to setup Buefy.

Probably that comparing both a new project and an old one and transferring the configuration is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Shame it has to be this way but at least I'm trying to add it to a new project, not an existing one I've done loads of work on. The config seemed the same, as I say, but I take your point about the differences in config perhaps being elsewhere.